# Matlab Fill zeros matric based on array

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

So i have this data

```
F =

     1
     1
     2
     3
     1
     2
     1
     1
```

and zeros matric

```
NM =

     0     0     0
     0     0     0
     0     0     0
```

i have rules, from the lis of array make connection for each variabel, from the F data the connection should be

```
1&1, 1&2, 2&3, 3&1, 1&2, 2&1, 1&1
```

each connection represent column and row value on NM matric, and if there is connection the value must be +1

so from the connection above the new matric should be

```
NNM=
2 2 0
1 0 1
1 0 0
```

im trying to code like this

```
[G H]=size(NM)
    for i=1:G
        j=2:G
        if F(i)==A(j)
            (NM(i,j))+1
        else
            NM(i,j)=0
        end
    end
    NNM=NM
```

but there is no change from the NM matric?
what shoul i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do

```
F = [1 1 2 3 1 2 1 1];

NM = zeros(3, 3);

for i=1:(numel(F)-1)
    NM(F(i), F(i+1))=NM(F(i), F(i+1))+1;
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`sparse`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) (and then convert to [`full`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html)) as follows:

```
NM = full(sparse(F(1:end-1), F(2:end), 1));
```

Comment: I really like this solution, it is very elegant. But seems like the basic loop is about two times faster, at least for the three dimensional case.

Answer (score 0):

```
list = [1 1 ; 1 2 ; 2 3 ; 3 1 ; 1 2 ; 2 1 ; 1 1 ] ;
[nx,ny] = size(list) ;
NM = zeros(3) ;
for i = 1:nx
    for j = 1:ny
        NM(list(i,1),list(i,2)) = NM(list(i,1),list(i,2)) + 1/2 ;
    end
end
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!